# C# stuck at db call even oracle clear the session automatically after around 30 mins

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle

I am using the C# windows service. I started Timer with 10 seconds.

1. In every 10 seconds, I called the method, it executes only when thread is null or in suspended state, which start the thread and inside the thread, it calls the oracle db proc.
2. But when db does not respond after 1 or 2 hr. Oracle clear the session after approx. 30 mins but c# Thread does not receive any communication from oracle and still stuck in oracle db call.

Any help?

```cs
        private void objTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((_objThread == null) || (_objThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Suspended))
                            {
                                    _objThread = new Thread(DBCallMethod);                                   
                                    _objThread.Start();
                                }
      }



        private void DBCallMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                //DB Called to update the recods.
                //stuck here while making db call, even though oracle automatically clear the session after approx 30 mins, cursor still stuck here.
               //resolve by restarting the service again.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log the exception using event log

            }
            finally
            {
                //log the complete state using event log
                if (_objThread.IsAlive)
                {
                    _objThread.Suspend();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: as you said your `try/catch/finally` block is never executes (which means that `try` part of this block is never executes, I suppose), why do you think that specificly `finally` part of it will be executed?

Comment: because in log file, I am seeing that thread started to execute again without suspending it in finally block. Log file does not logged the catch and finally block logs.

Comment: There is no good use case for `Thread.Suspend`. I'm not clear on what you're *trying* to do with this, but whatever it is, it shouldn't involve calling `Thread.Suspend`, and certainly not from within a `finally`. Use proper synchronization primitives, like a monitor or manual reset event. If external code suspends a thread, abandon it and move on. (This is a bad thing, and will eventually necessitate a restart of your process if enough threads are suspended like this, but there's not much you can do about that.)

Comment: Why do you need to bother with a thread suspension? For me it seems that what are trying to do, is much easier to achieve with a thread pool.

Comment: I found that a select query is stuck which is why data is not processing afterwards. But after 30-40 mins approx, oracle clear the session automatically but still the c# code is in running mode. My concern, how oracle clear the session automatically and also after clearing the session, it doesn't return to the c# code. Why?...Remember this hanging happen sometimes only..say once or twice in a week.